# How to input mask in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, github, keras

I want to use this [Surface Distance Based Metrics](https://github.com/deepmind/surface-distance)
the code is

```
import surface_distance as surfdist

surface_distances = surfdist.compute_surface_distances(
    mask_gt, mask_pred, spacing_mm=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
hd_dist_95 = surfdist.compute_robust_hausdorff(surface_distances, 95)
```

How to input the mask_gt and mask_pred? I tried to did it in this way,

```
import surface_distance as surfdist

def hausdorff_distance(y_true, y_pred):

  surface_distances = surfdist.compute_surface_distances(
          y_true, y_pred, spacing_mm=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0))
  hd_dist_95 = surfdist.compute_robust_hausdorff(surface_distances, 95)
  return hd_dist_95
```

but it return

```
TypeError: Input 'x' of 'LogicalOr' Op has type float32 that does not match expected type of bool.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sound like your loss function expect to get boolean tensor, while your gt tensor is of type "float" (probably some array with values 0,1?). try to cast the tensor to bool, for example:

```
tf.keras.backend.cast(y_true, 'bool')
```

Comment: I used your code `mask_gt = tf.cast(y_true,bool), mask_pred = tf.cast(y_pred,bool)` but it return another error `NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (metrics_6/hausdorff_distance/or:0) to a numpy array.`

Comment: Does this error occors during the line of the casting, or inside the internal loss function? if it's inside the "compute_surface_distances" loss, maybe it expects to get numpy arrays and not tensors? I'm not familiar with this repository.

Comment: I want to use it as metric in Keras for training, `model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3), 
             loss=bce_dice_loss, metrics=['accuracy',iou_metric,hausdorff_distance])`